# Get all articles by page size of 10 and each article get populated some needed users' information

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregates

I have created 2 models namely user, article. Their data structure are like below;

```
const userSchema = Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  password: String
});
const User = mongoose.model(‘user’, userSchema);
module.exports = User;

——

const articleSchema = Schema({
  liked: Array,  // liked contains users’ _id who like this article
  content: String
})
const Article = mongoose.model(‘article’, articleSchema);
module.exports = Article

——
```

I want to get all articles by page size of 10 and each article get populated some users’ info who like this article.

For example, let’s imagine the data of user table and article table like this:

```
users = [
 { 
    _id: 1,
    name: ‘a’,
    email: ‘a.com’,
    password: ‘a’
 },
 { 
    _id: 2,
    name: ‘b’,
    email: ‘b.com’,
    password: ‘b’
 }
]

articles = [
  {
    _id: 1,
    liked: [1,2],
    content: “a&b”
  },
  {
     _id: 2,
     liked: [1],
     content: “a”
  }
]
```

The desired result is:

```
  articles = [
   {
      _id: 1,
      liked: [
      { 
         _id: 1,
         name: ‘a’,
         email: ‘a.com’,
         password: ‘a’
       },
       { 
         _id: 2,
         name: ‘b’,
         email: ‘b.com’,
         password: ‘b’
       }
     ],
     content: “a&b”
   },
   {
       _id: 2,
       liked: [
       { 
          _id: 1,
          name: ‘a’,
          email: ‘a.com’,
          password: ‘a’
        }
       ],
        content: “a”
    }
]
```

I tried to resolve this matter  by using `Model.find(query)` and `Model.aggregate(pipeline)`  but each of the two approaches had pros and cons and couldn’t reached the good result.  Please give me an advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you have shared a simple `$lookup` in an [Model.aggregate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#Aggregate()) query would get you that output:

```js
const articles = await Article.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "liked",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "liked"
    }
  }
]);
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mj5WfLIQisv) for a working example.

However, if you were to change your schema to use referenced docs then you could use [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) to replace each `_id` in the `Article.liked` array with the corresponding `User` document at the time of query retrieval. Either way will work.

This is how you would use populate:

```js
const articleSchema = Schema({
  liked: [{ 
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      ref: 'User' // create a reference to User
   }],  
  content: String
})
```

then do

```js
const articles = await Article.find().populate({path: 'liked', model: User});
```

**Note**: this example with `populate()` works on the predicate that each `User._id` field of each `User` document is of the mongoose `ObjectId` type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It sure does. So the main point is that modify the article's Schema. In order to every element of 'liked' connect to the users table. Right?

Comment: @BobMartin That is correct. The `aggregate` way with `$lookup` allows you to do it with strings, numbers ObjectIds etc so is very useful but `populate` is preferred in mongoose with the `_id` field.